# Get count of two column group on neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a table of Packages like

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Pack1 | 1.0.0 |
| Pack1 | 1.0.1 |
| Pack2 | 2.0.0 |

I want to return a list of those packages with more than one version
In SQL it would be something like

```sql
 SELECT Name from Package
 GROUP BY Name
 having count(Version) > 1
```

how would I do something like this on Cypher (with or without apoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivalent of group by in sql to neo4j.

```
Sql:
    SELECT Name from Package
     GROUP BY Name
     having count(Version) > 1 


Neo4j:
    MATCH (p:Package)
    WITH p.name as name, count(p.version) as cnt WHERE cnt > 1
    RETURN name

Result:
╒═══════╕
│"name" │
╞═══════╡
│"Pack1"│
└───────┘
```